# Unable to access mailgun credentials with process.env in a node app

Tags: node.js, smtp, mailgun, api-key

I have a node app, and in the `.env` file, I've stored the credentials- `api_key` and `domain`. Now, I can't access the credentials anywhere in my application, let alone the part where I need them. I tried `process.env.api_key` and `process.env.domain`, and got the following error resulting in my app getting crashed even before compiling.

**`Error: apiKey value must be defined!`**

Here's my **auth** object:

```js
const auth = {
  auth: {
    api_key: process.env.api_key,
    domain: process.env.domain  
  }
}
```

**.env**

```js
api_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
domain="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.org"
```

When I try to use the credentials directly, everything works fine, but doing that is not a good idea, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a `.env` alone won't do anything, since Node.js doesn't handle that file. You need to load it, you may want to use: [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package for that.

```
require('dotenv').config(); // very beginning of the file

// process.env.api_key will have a value now.
// rest of your code.
```

`dotenv` `require` **must be** before any other `require`.

Comment: I have that already. I'm using other credentials as well through `.env`. The issue is with mailgun's credentials.

Comment: Show the rest of your code, maybe you're loading the other package before loading `dotenv`

Comment: Check update, put `dotenv` require at the very beginning of the file.